# Mac shortcut but with gChrome open

Tags: shortcut, keybindings

I defined a shortcut on my mac that works if I am focused on "Finder", but when I open g-chrome and then type my shortcut, nothing happens.

I suspect the issue is that g-chrome "override" my shortcut or something...any ideas on how to solve this?

Here is how I defined it

[image]

Comment: What's the shortcut? What does it do? How did you define it? Have you checked Chrome's menus for a conflict?

Comment: cmd+shift+L and it opens a process I defined myself in the app Shurtcuts (basically open note app and I can inpute text and save it).

Comment: Is it defined as global, or Finder only? Chrome doesn't seem to have anything that would block it.

Comment: I added a pic of how I defined it in the message...does that make sense?